# Cantor-Lebesgue function and binary expansion

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering the differences between Cantor-Lebesgue function and binary expansion of a number. Cantor-Lebesgue function defined as $F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k/2^k$, if $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k/3^k$, where $b_k=a_k/2$ and $a_k\in\{0,2\}$. The binary expansion of a number is very similar to this function. Is this function represent the binary expansion on cantor set$\mathscr C$ ?
This confusion comes from the exercise of "real analysis" by stein.

Comment: $F(x)$ is not the same as the binary expansion of $x$ for  $x \in C$.

Comment: Can you tell me the differences?

Answer (score 0):

You take the ternary (base 3) expansion of points of $\mathscr{C}$.  Each such point has a ternary expansion not using the digit $1$.

Then you just change every $2$ to a $1$ and consider the resulting [infinite] string as a binary expansion of a real number.